# How to turn on android application through external signal?

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc, android-bluetooth, rfid

I want to turn on an android application by external signal like bluetooth, rfid, nfc or any other. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use broadcast receiver

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the application is started automatically by the Android system, when needed. In case of Bluetooth Classic if you open the server socket to accept connections, you app's process will be kept around.

Somre other services use so-called `Receiver`, which is declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, and the system starts the app as needed (this is the case for Bluetooth LE, alarms or GCM messages etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a service which runs in background with which you can trigger an app launch(using BLE signal,sms etc.,)